# Docker + JHipster + Memory usage goes up

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose, jhipster

I created JHipster projects and trying to execute it over a linux machine. All containers are created just fine, I can see them with "docker ps" and look at usage with "docker stats".

However, memory keeps going up and up.. eventualy my laptop (core i5, 10gb RAM) stops responding and die!

I tried with mem_limit on each service definition on docker_compose.yml, and I can see the limit working on docker stats... however memory keeps going up and when the container gets > 95% usage it goes dead... container stops working and is removed. So.. this setup just prevents my pc to die.. but nothing else.

I also tried with set ENV JAVA_OPTS for -Xmx and other memory parameters in docker_compose.yml... but the result is the same.

The registry, gateway, a business microservices and UAA need at least 1.5GB to not die and be able to start, other images/containers (mysql, elasticsearch, etc) can work with 512m. However having 4 x 1.5GB and several 512mb is consuming all my memory. JHipster Registry should be ok with 512mb.. I setup a registry on Heroku with 512mb and it just works.

I'm running elementary OS (ubuntu 14.04 based), 64 bits, Kernel 3.19.0-59-generic, Java 1.8, Docker version 1.11.2 build b9f10c9, and I did the cgroups configuracion on grub for memory (from docker installation guide). Here is the outout of cat /proc/cgroups:

`#subsys_name   hierarchy   num_cgroups enabled
cpuset  1   4   1
cpu 2   4   1
cpuacct 3   4   1
memory  4   7   1
devices 5   4   1
freezer 6   4   1
net_cls 7   4   1
blkio   8   4   1
perf_event  9   4   1
net_prio    10  4   1
hugetlb 11  4   1`

One more thing.. I tried the projects from this repo https://github.com/kbastani/spring-cloud-microservice-example and have exactly the same issue.. memory goes up and up.

I hope you will be able to help on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The container's need more memory, limiting how much they can have doesn't change that.

When the memory gets too high (95%) the Linux OOM killer steps in to save your system from eminent doom (see [OOM Killer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153585/how-oom-killer-decides-which-process-to-kill-first))

TL;DR
Run less containers or get more memory.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Yes, on a prod environment (servers) is expected to have more memory.. but not too much when working on dev. I was looking into OOM and you can disable it (always together with mem_limit defined)... however disable is not available on docker_compose, just in docker run. I'm also thinking that images could be unnecesary too heavy, I'm looking at this article http://www.developer.com/design/a-guide-to-docker-image-optimization.html to reduce images. Anyway, there should be more performance boosts we can apply.. in other case how Heroku gets this working with 300mb?